# How to import a modified class in python?

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn, python-import

I used in my project scikit-learn library and for various reasons I had to modify some classes inside the library.
In particular these classes are called by the algorithms that I used for classification purposes.
So in example I have in my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
```

Now I want to import in my code these modified classes, in a way that scikit-learn library remains the same and when the algorithm is called it uses my classes (that obviously are in a separate folder) instead of the original ones.
What is the right way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modules you import are basically just python-files themselves (*.py). Python knows where to look for them. E.g. Sklearn might be installed into the package-folder. Python will also look for it in the folder from which your current script is run.

You can copy the code for that class, manipulate how you wish and then save it to a new .py file within your project folder. If you name that python-file `myNewClasses.py` and the new class `My_SGDClassifier` you can go like

```
from myNewClasses import My_SGFClassifier
```

This way you do not interfer with the original sklearn-class. You can also have several classes, functions or whatever you like in that file/module and import them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do something like this I would use `virtualenv` for sure:

1. Use `virtualenv myProject` to create your virtual environment
2. `cd myProject` and enter `bin/activate`
3. You can `pip install` sklearn and rebuild/modify or copy your modified sklearn to `myProject/lib/python2.7`
4. Just import it and use it.

Note that your virtual env packages will be completly separated from your computer environment